# Shifted harmonic number sums

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form

We know that the closed form of the generalized Euler sums involving harmonic number
$$\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{{H_n}}}{{{n^k}}}}  = \frac{1}{2}\left\{ {\left( {k + 2} \right)\zeta \left( {k + 1} \right) - \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{k - 2} {\zeta \left( {k - i} \right)\zeta \left( {i + 1} \right)} } \right\},$$
where $k\ge2$ is a positive integer and the harmonic number $H_n^{(k)}$ is defined by $$H^{(k)}_n:=\sum\limits_{j=1}^n\frac {1}{j^k}\quad {\rm and}\quad H^{(k)}_0:=0.$$
Next, we defined the generalized shifted harmonic number by 
$$H_\alpha ^{\left( m \right)} = \zeta \left( m \right) - \zeta \left( {m,\alpha  + 1} \right),\;\alpha \notin  N^-,\ 2\leq m\in N,$$
and for $m=1$,
$${H_\alpha } \equiv H_\alpha ^{\left( 1 \right)} = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\left( {\frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{{k + \alpha }}} \right)} .$$
My question is that how to calculate the closed form of the following shifted harmonic number sums
$$\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{{H_{n + \alpha }}}}{{{n^k}}}}=?$$
it can be expressed in terms of (Hurwitz) zeta values?

Comment: For $~a=\tfrac12~$ we have $~H_{n+1/2}~=~2\cdot\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^n\frac1{2k+1}~-~2\ln2.~$

Comment: In other words, $H_{n+1/2}~=~2~H_{2n+2}-H_{n+1}-2\ln2.$

Comment: A [related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1409811) question.